# Scala insert element into sorted array in log(N)

Tags: scala

I have a sorted Array and I would like to insert a new element in logarithmic time.

I want to do something like this:

```
def addElem(Array[Int] data, Int x) {
            val pos = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(data,x);
            data.insertAfter(pos, x);
}
```

Can I do this with an Array?

Should I try a different data structure?

Comment: How could insertion to an array be log(N) when it needs O(n) to move part of array to make space for new element?

Comment: Does your sorted collection need to be able to handle duplicate elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider scala collections performance charasteristics:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

There are two types of collections that provide `Log` complexity for insert operation. They are: `TreeSet, TreeMap` (mutable and immutable).

I would suggest use them.

Regarding `Arrays.binarySearch` usage. 
It will not work as most likely you array will not contains `x` element, so it returns `-1`. 
Definitely you can implement `binarySearch` on `Array[Int]` by yourself that satisfy your needs.